# SOAP UI - Step executed on init phase (only once and reused)

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the following scenario:

Step 1) load from a file via groovy the content of a file in base64 format. (very big file)

Step 2) assign this base64 to a parameter

Step 3) execute the request with this parameter

If i execute a load test even 2GB is not enough cause 20 threads can easily consume that.

So is there a way to reuse the file that is loaded ,once among different threads in order not to load on each execution of the test case the big file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a property (I think any level would work.. TestCase, TestPlan, Project) for the long string.

Read the string in using a groovy script at the plan or project level and put the base64 value in that property.

From the load test, reuse the data from the property instead of reading from a file.

That should allow the threads to share it.

Let me know if it doesn't work.  I am still downloading soapui to my new desktop 3.4/117MB.